# How to import csv from external website in Neo4j?

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

my import from "disk" **IS** working with this command

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///question.csv" AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|' MERGE (:QuestionContainer {ID: line.ID, GUID: line.GUID, History: line.History})
```

but it **IS NOT** working with this command

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://www.example.com:8091/question.csv" AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|' MERGE (:QuestionContainer {ID: line.ID, GUID: line.GUID, History: line.History})
```

error messages:

Couldn't load the external resource at: http://www.example.com:8091/question.csv

my neo4j config file looks like

```
dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=512M
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=100M size
dbms.directories.logs=/logs
dbms.directories.import=/import
apoc.import.url.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=true
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
```

wget http://www.example.com:8091/question.csv works!
Any hint? Using Version: 4.1.3

Thanks rob

Answer (score 0):

Looks like  I had a docker-compsoe problem with accessing the port 8091 and the "exterenal" url from one container to the other. Now I use an internal link and it works.

never the less i think others ports then 80/443 are not working! no time to test ... but a hint for others with simmilars problems